# Derive that a sum equals $\log(1+x)-\log(1-x)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, logarithms

Show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n-1}}{n-1/2}=\log(1+x)-\log(1-x)$$

---

I got a series for $\log(1+x)$ so by replacing the $x$ by $-x$ I got that
$$\left (\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{(n+1)}\frac{x^n}{n}  \right )-\left ( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{(n+1)}\frac{(-x)^n}{n} \right )\\=\log(1+x)-\log(1-x)$$

all of this is for $|x|<1$. I do not know how to proceed with this because I should be able to rewrite the two sums into the one in the first equation or is there an easier approach I am overseeing?

Comment: You can combine the two infinite sums together, and you'll note that a lot of the terms are zero.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I have tried this without luck. I can not make them resemble the one in question, unfortunately.

Comment: The key is reindexing the sum. Since the sum has only odd powers of $x^n$, you can instead write them as a sum over all powers of the form $x^{2n-1}$.

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{x^{2n-1}}{n-1/2}=\frac{2x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}.$$ Use this together the @eyeballfrog`s comment.

Comment: @DiegoMath I have gotten that far ^^.  The problem is mainly with the 2 sums to resemble that

Comment: @eyeballfrog I am not sure on how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First observe that:

$$\begin{aligned}
\ln(1-x)
&=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(-x)^n}{n}
\\ \\ &=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(-1)^n x^n}{n}
\\ \\ &=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{2n+1}\frac{x^n}{n}
\\ \\ &=
-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}
\end{aligned}$$

Thus we can write the sum as:

$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n-1}}{n-1/2}
&=
2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}
\\ \\ &=
2\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{2n}\right)
\\ \\ &=
2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(x^2)^n}{n}
\\ \\&=
-2\ln(1-x)+\ln(1-x^2)
\\ \\ &=
\ln\left(\frac{(1-x)(1+x)}{(1-x)^2}\right)
\\ \\ &=
\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)
\\ \\ &=
\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)
\end{aligned}$$